# Approximating points in $\{0,1\}^n$

Tags: combinatorics, coding-theory, combinatorial-designs

Let $A=\{0,1\}^n$ with distance $d(x,y)=\sum_i |x_i-y_i|$ (i.e. for example with $n=2$ we have $d([0,1],[1,0])=2$).

Given $m<n$ how well can we "approximate $A$" with a subset of cardinality $m$?

Formally, I want to know

$$g(m):=\inf_{S\subset A,\ \#S=m} \sup_{x \in A} d(x,S)$$

I tried to do it by myself, founding some trivial cases
$$g(1)=n$$
$$g(2)=\frac{n}{2}$$

but then I can't proceed. Also I think that such a simple problem must have been treated by someone before me

Comment: What does $d(x,S)$ mean if $S$ is a set? $\min\limits_{y \in S} d(x,y)$ ?

Comment: Your question is related to binary covering codes. Namely, $g(m)\le d$ if and only if $K_2(n,d)\le m$, where $K_2(n,d)$ is the size of the smallest binary covering code with distance $d$. Determining $K_2(n,d)$ is in general a hard open problem, but some known bounds are available on [Gerzson Kéri's website](http://old.sztaki.hu/~keri/codes/index.htm).

Comment: So, in simple words: you have $n$ cities connected by roads. You want to optimally place $m$ hospitals in some of the cities, such that the worst case distance to the nearest hospital over the entire country is minimized, and want to find that distance. Further, your road graph is a hypercube

Comment: But yes, I agree with Henry that something is ill-defined at the moment. Could you please answer Henry's question? Based on his definition $g(x) \leq 2$, because you always compute the distance between two bits only. Based on your example, I assume that the distance is a more complicated function.